# Не работает Random Forest в LightGBM

Tags: python, машинное-обучение

У меня проблема с Random Forest в LightGBM:

```
X_train_g, X_test_g, y_train_g, y_test_g = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3, shuffle=True)
train_data = lgb.Dataset(X_train_g, label=y_train_g)
param={ 'boosting': 'random_forest'}
ppn=lgb.train(param, train_data)
y_pred_g = ppn.predict(X_test_g)
r2=r2_score(y_pred_g, y_test_g)
print('R2=', r2)
```

Если сменить Random forest на gbdt, dart или goss, тогда все работает. Но если использую Rf, то вылетает следующая ошибка:

```
LightGBMError: Check failed: config->bagging_freq > 0 && config->bagging_fraction < 1.0f && config->bagging_fraction > 0.0f at c:\users\builder\appdata\local\temp\pip-req-build-7miknwb4\compile\src\boosting\rf.hpp, line 35
```

Я видел похожие вопросы, но там проблемы были в line 26-28, и советы по решению соответствующих проблем не дали результатов. Пожалуйста, помогите мне.

Comment: А если попробовать выставить указанные параметры в какие-то значения, которые удовлетворят этой проверке? И посмотреть бы, какие значения выставляются там по умолчанию.

Comment: Я немного поигрался с настройками, кажется, что случайный лес не работает для регрессии и классификации. Зато он вроде заработал для ранжирования. Но тут ключевое слово "вроде", у меня нет нормального датасета для проверки. В любом случае, если кто-то сталкивался с этой проблемой, хотелось был услышать мнение бывалых)

Comment: Да думаю просто никто не использует `RF` из `LightGBM` от слова совсем. `RF` давно есть в `Scikit-Learn`, поэтому все используют тот `RF` исторически, а `LightGBM` используют ради его родных бустингов.